# Can you use `.apply()` on the emit method of EventEmitter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I'm trying to do...

```
EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter

events = new EventEmitter()

events.emit.apply(null, ['eventname', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'])
```

...but it doesn't seem to work or throw an error, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Apply method you need inform two arguments:
A valid scope (what value will be the "this" inside the method) and the argument array.

Comment: Right, yes, I do this.

Comment: Try pass a valid scope

Comment: `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object, no?

Comment: I guess thats only in the browser maybe? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the `emit()` function of the EventEmitter is expecting `this` to be an actual EventEmitter object. The following seems to work if you pass in the `events` object.

`events.emit.apply(events, ['eventname', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'])`

Though at this point, might as well just call

`emit('eventname', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')`

I am guessing the `emit()` method is looping over an internal list of registered events to see if there is a matching one. Not sure if this helps, just something I came across today working with events...